# Types of Discrete numbers

Tags: number-theory

I was trying to figure out difference between Discrete and Continuous numbers, and from [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/206/what-is-the-difference-between-discrete-data-and-continuous-data)

I got my answer.

However, I am confused on a small point. On the same above link, a user has written:

"Data can be discrete without being restricted to integers. Or numbers, for that matter. It's always possible to represent discrete data with integers, but that doesn't mean the data can only take such values. –  walkytalky Jul 23 '10 at 16:06"

Does that mean that if I have a set$ A = \{0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5\}$, can I call it a set of discrete numbers?

(means, there is no restriction for a number being discrete to be integer. If it is not uncountable and countably finite, it can discrete, even in decimal form).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This belongs to stats.stackexchange, I think. But yes, a discrete set of numbers need not consist of integers.

Comment: Yes, your set A is discrete.  However if you defined it as $A = (0.5, 1.5)$ then it would be continuous (the parenthesis here denotes an interval).  But this question might belong in stats...

Comment: You can have a look at the Wikipedia page on [discrete spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space) for a formal definition. SubSeven gives you an intuitive idea of what this means in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An intuitive way of thinking about it might be as follows: if it's not continuous, it's discrete, and it's continuous whenever you can pick any two numbers in the set and there's always a number between them.

In your example $A = \{0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5\}$ I can pick two numbers let's say 0.5 and 1.5, but I can't choose any numbers between them (that are in A).

However, if $A = (0.5,3.5)$ (the interval from 0.5 to 3.5) then I can pick any two numbers in that range (let's say 1.0 and 1.2) and there's always a number between them (for example 1.1).

There's likely a much stronger definition out there, but this is probably the easiest way to think about it...

Comment: Bundle of thanks for great explanation. (And also thanks to other contributors for their valuable time).

Comment: You're welcome - although this definition will suffice intuitively, you have to be careful: for example the Rational numbers aren't continuous (the proper term in fact would be that they are not a **continuum**) since they have "holes" (where irrational numbers are). The term "continuous" is generally reserved for functions and in this case continuity is defined easiest using limits. As I said, there are stronger ways of defining these ideas, but my original answer I've found to be a good way of thinking about it (as long as you're mindful of "holes").